# IOS apple sign in cannot get email but can get user name

Tags: ios

As the title suggests, I have implemented Sign in with Apple. After submitting my app online, I found that I can not get the user's email while I can get the username. 
I collect the username and email and I found I can not get user email sometimes when the user first authorizes my app. Any reply appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

The section [Send Information to Your App Servers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple) on the Apple Developer website states that this information is only returned to you the first time the user authenticates with Apple Sign In. You will need to store those details yourself in order to retrieve them again on subsequent logins.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I can`t get email sometimes even user authenticate the first time.